# Javascript multiplying .value

Tags: javascript

I am trying to multiply 3 numbers from two dropdowns and one text-input. I know it sounds easy, but I have been trying for a lot of hours now!

When i try asking the developer-tool in Chrome, it correctly return the values (In console.log I write: kroner.value).
But I can not multiply it in the line "var total". Do i have to change the order of something? Or maybe even rethink the whole code? :-)

Thanks a lot!

```js
//Herfra starter udregningen af drikkepenge
function udregn() {
    var kroner = document.getElementById("kroner").value;
    var land = document.getElementById("land").value;
    var kvalitet = document.getElementById("kvalitet").value;

    //Hvis alle oplysninger ikke tastes
    if (kroner === "" || land === 0 || kvalitet === 0) {
        alert("Udfyld venligst alle felter.");
        return;
    }

    //Selve udregningen
    var total = kroner * land * kvalitet;

     //round to two decimal places
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  //next line allows us to always have two digits after decimal point
  total = total.toFixed(2);

    //Vis drikkepengene
    document.getElementById("tipbelob").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;
}


document.getElementById("regnformig").onclick = function () {
    udregn();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a2afba;
}

#drikkepengeboks {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #e8eaeb;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: black 0 20px 20px 0;
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

select {
  border: gold 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  border: gold 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}

h3 {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #a2afba;
  border: gold 2px solid;
  box-shadow: black 0 4px 4px 0;
}

#tipbelob {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Drikkepengeudregner</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="drikkepengeboks">

<h1>Drikkepengeudregner</h1>
<p>Få hjælp til at udregne, hvor mange drikkepenge du skal give.
  Udfyld nedenstående og se beløbet.


  <h2>Hvad lyder regningen på?</h2>
  <input id="kroner" type="number" placeholder="Beløbet i kr.">

<h2>Hvor befinder du dig?</h2>
<select id="land">
  <option disabled selected value="0">-- Vælg venligst et land --</option>

  <option value="0,15">Danmark</option>
  <option value="0,05">Gran Canaria</option>
  <option value="0,10">Kuching</option>
</select>


<h2>Hvor god var mad og service?</h2>
<select id="kvalitet">
    <option disabled selected value="0">-- Vælg venligst din vurdering --</option>

  <option value="1,1">Rigtig god</option>
  <option value="1">Godkendt</option>
  <option value="0,9">Under forventning</option>
</select>

<h3 id="regnformig">Vis mig beløbet!</h3>



<div id="tipbelob">
    kr. <span id="tip">0.00</span>
  </div>

</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: .value from an input is always a string. You need to convert those to numbers before you do math. Maybe something like `var total = Number(kroner) * Number(land) * Number(kvalitet);`

Comment: @Brant The multiplication operator will convert it automatically. Only `+` requires you to do it, since it does concatenation otherwise.

Comment: The numbers values should have a dot as decimal separator, instead of a comma

Comment: @IronyStack uh... I really feel like that's a terrible way to do it. Casting is hard to track as it is, doing short-hand *inside* an evaluation is really bad for readability.

Comment: `0,15` is not a valid number

Comment: Thank you. I had stared blindly! The dot instead of comma did it!
Thanks everybody! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the comma with a dot in your HTML and it works.

```js
//Herfra starter udregningen af drikkepenge
function udregn() {
    var kroner = document.getElementById("kroner").value;
    var land = document.getElementById("land").value;
    var kvalitet = document.getElementById("kvalitet").value;

    //Hvis alle oplysninger ikke tastes
    if (kroner === "" || land === 0 || kvalitet === 0) {
        alert("Udfyld venligst alle felter.");
        return;
    }

    //Selve udregningen
    var total = kroner * land * kvalitet;

     //round to two decimal places
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  //next line allows us to always have two digits after decimal point
  total = total.toFixed(2);

    //Vis drikkepengene
    document.getElementById("tipbelob").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;
}


document.getElementById("regnformig").onclick = function () {
    udregn();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a2afba;
}

#drikkepengeboks {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #e8eaeb;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: black 0 20px 20px 0;
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

select {
  border: gold 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  border: gold 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}

h3 {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #a2afba;
  border: gold 2px solid;
  box-shadow: black 0 4px 4px 0;
}

#tipbelob {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Drikkepengeudregner</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="drikkepengeboks">

<h1>Drikkepengeudregner</h1>
<p>Få hjælp til at udregne, hvor mange drikkepenge du skal give.
  Udfyld nedenstående og se beløbet.


  <h2>Hvad lyder regningen på?</h2>
  <input id="kroner" type="number" placeholder="Beløbet i kr.">

<h2>Hvor befinder du dig?</h2>
<select id="land">
  <option disabled selected value="0">-- Vælg venligst et land --</option>

  <option value="0.15">Danmark</option>
  <option value="0.05">Gran Canaria</option>
  <option value="0.10">Kuching</option>
</select>


<h2>Hvor god var mad og service?</h2>
<select id="kvalitet">
    <option disabled selected value="0">-- Vælg venligst din vurdering --</option>

  <option value="1.1">Rigtig god</option>
  <option value="1">Godkendt</option>
  <option value="0.9">Under forventning</option>
</select>

<h3 id="regnformig">Vis mig beløbet!</h3>



<div id="tipbelob">
    kr. <span id="tip">0.00</span>
  </div>

</div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @AndersKunnerup No problem.

Answer (score 0):

The total is `NaN` because the multiplication is performed on invalid numbers. The values should have a dot for decimal separator, instead of a comma.

Fixed snippet:

```js
//Herfra starter udregningen af drikkepenge
function udregn() {
    var kroner = document.getElementById("kroner").value;
    var land = document.getElementById("land").value;
    var kvalitet = document.getElementById("kvalitet").value;

    //Hvis alle oplysninger ikke tastes
    if (kroner === "" || land === 0 || kvalitet === 0) {
        alert("Udfyld venligst alle felter.");
        return;
    }

    //Selve udregningen
    var total = kroner * land * kvalitet;
    
    // check value of total in the console 
    // console.log('total', total)

     //round to two decimal places
  total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100;
  //next line allows us to always have two digits after decimal point
  total = total.toFixed(2);

    //Vis drikkepengene
    document.getElementById("tipbelob").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML = total;
}


document.getElementById("regnformig").onclick = function () {
    udregn();
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #a2afba;
}

#drikkepengeboks {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #e8eaeb;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: black 0 20px 20px 0;
}

h1 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p {
  margin: auto;
  width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

select {
  border: gold 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}

input {
  border: gold 1px solid;
  width: 50%;
}

h3 {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #a2afba;
  border: gold 2px solid;
  box-shadow: black 0 4px 4px 0;
}

#tipbelob {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Drikkepengeudregner</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="drikkepengeboks">

<h1>Drikkepengeudregner</h1>
<p>Få hjælp til at udregne, hvor mange drikkepenge du skal give.
  Udfyld nedenstående og se beløbet.


  <h2>Hvad lyder regningen på?</h2>
  <input id="kroner" type="number" placeholder="Beløbet i kr.">

<h2>Hvor befinder du dig?</h2>
<select id="land">
  <option disabled selected value="0">-- Vælg venligst et land --</option>

  <option value="0.15">Danmark</option>
  <option value="0.05">Gran Canaria</option>
  <option value="0.10">Kuching</option>
</select>


<h2>Hvor god var mad og service?</h2>
<select id="kvalitet">
    <option disabled selected value="0">-- Vælg venligst din vurdering --</option>

  <option value="1.1">Rigtig god</option>
  <option value="1">Godkendt</option>
  <option value="0.9">Under forventning</option>
</select>

<h3 id="regnformig">Vis mig beløbet!</h3>



<div id="tipbelob">
    kr. <span id="tip">0.00</span>
  </div>

</div>
</body>



</html>
```